# Как доработать чат на ASP.NET Core и WebSocket?

Tags: websocket, asp.net-core, чат

Я реализовал прототип чата, в котором реализовано добавление сообщений с текстом и никнеймом пользователя. Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно оперировать более сложными данными: имя, фамилия, эмейл, два нужных ID, дата добавления сообщения, а также я хочу добавлять сообщения в базу данных.
Я создал middleware-класс для сокета:

```
public class ChatWebSocketMiddleWare
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, WebSocket> _sockets = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, WebSocket>();
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ChatWebSocketMiddleWare(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
            return;
        }

        CancellationToken ct = context.RequestAborted;
        WebSocket currentSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
        var socketId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        _sockets.TryAdd(socketId, currentSocket);

        while (true)
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }

            var response = await ReceiveStringAsync(currentSocket, ct);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
            {
                if (currentSocket.State != WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    break;
                }

                continue;
            }

            foreach (var socket in _sockets)
            {
                if (socket.Value.State != WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                await SendStringAsync(socket.Value, response, ct);
            }
        }
        WebSocket dummy;
        _sockets.TryRemove(socketId, out dummy);

        await currentSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Closing", ct);
        currentSocket.Dispose();
    }

    private static Task SendStringAsync(WebSocket socket, string data, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);
        return socket.SendAsync(segment, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, ct);
    }

    private static async Task<string> ReceiveStringAsync(WebSocket socket, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[8192]);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WebSocketReceiveResult result;
            do
            {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, ct);
                ms.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);
            }
            while (!result.EndOfMessage);

            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            if (result.MessageType != WebSocketMessageType.Text)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // Encoding UTF8: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.6
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Есть js-скрипт на странице с чатом на для отправления сообщений в сокет:

```
@section Scripts{
<script>
    $(function () {
        var userName = "testUser";

        var protocol = location.protocol === "https:" ? "wss:" : "ws:";
        var wsUri = protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
        var socket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
        socket.onopen = e => {
            console.log("socket opened", e);
        };

        socket.onclose = function (e) {
            console.log("socket closed", e);
        };

        socket.onmessage = function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            $('#msgs').append(e.data + '<br />');
        };

        socket.onerror = function (e) {
            console.error(e.data);
        };

        $('#MessageField').keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which != 13) {
                return;
            }

            e.preventDefault();

            var jacksRank = $("#MessageField").data("firstname");
            var message = jacksRank + ": " + $('#MessageField').val();
            socket.send(message);
            $('#MessageField').val('');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Как можно передавать сложный объект класса такого плана:

```
public class UserPlusText
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Как видно из функций ReceiveStringAsync и SendStringAsync, а также js-скрипта приложение оперирует просто строками, не могу понять, как оперировать сложным объектом.